# A question about constructible real numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This question was asked in my Field theory quiz and I was unable to solve it. So, I am asking for help here.

> Let c and d be constructible real numbers. Show that c+d and c-d are also constructible.

I am clear with the definition of constructible real numbers and related theorems but still I was unable to solve the question. I have studied related results from Algebra by THomas HUngerford.

Can you please give solution proving any 1 of them to be constructible. That would really help me.

Thank you.

Comment: How about constructing them by means of parallel translations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $l$ be a line containing two points $A$ and $B$ that are $c$ apart. Draw a circle with radius $d$ centred at $B$; it intersects $l$ at $C$ (closer to $A$) and $D$ (farther from $A$). Then $\overline{AC}=c-d$ and $\overline{AD}=c+d$.

This presumes $c\ge d\ge0$; other cases can be handled by basic arithmetic properties and interpreting distances along $l$ as signed, with $A$ at the origin.